# Use jQuery to remove global properties

Tags: jquery, css, styles

Below global properties were added to page :

```
* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Since there is not a 'none' option on these properties can jQuery be used to remove these properties from a page or div ?

Update :

Creating my own stylesheet :

```
* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

and importing it seems to fix this issue.

This seems to clear the cache location of where these styles are located ?
I don't know if this just an IE8 issue.

Comment: You can't 'remove' the styles; you can only overwrite them (with another value); unless you parse the [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets).

Comment: `content-box` is the default value for box sizing according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @David Thomas could you expand on how I might use document.styleSheets to remove the style ?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `content-box` instead (which [is the default](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0), the old CSS 2.1 behavior):

```
$("selector for the elements").css({
    "-webkit-box-sizing": "content-box",
    "-moz-box-sizing": "content-box",
    "box-sizing": "content-box"
});
```

You might also consider using this style instead for `border-box` (from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/)):

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ...prefixed versions as you see fit...*/
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  /* ...prefixed versions as you see fit...*/
}
```

If you do that, you can set `content-box` just on a container element, and the elements within it will all inherit it. Important when using widgets on your page that were designed for the old box model.

Comment: thanks, but no matter what I try border-box is not being overridden. Even though when I inspect the element I can see its been set to "content-box" but on IE8 its still being interpreted as "border-box"

Answer (score 0):

Better overwrite it in your own style sheet. 
    *{
     -webkit-box-sizing:content-box !important;
// like wise for others
   }

Can also try 'initial' as value

Comment: please see question update as similar to your answer seems to work, though I did not require !important. Why should this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("style").each(function(i, el) {  
  $(el).text(function(i, styles) {
    return styles.replace(/border-box/g, "")  
  })
});
```

```js
$("style").each(function(i, el) {  
  $(el).text(function(i, styles) {
    return styles.replace(/border-box/g, "")  
  })
});

$("*").each(function() {
  console.log(this.style.boxSizing)
})
```

```css
* {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


div {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: Is there a method to ignore certain styles ? For example, can your code be amended to ignore .customBox : http://jsfiddle.net/ca59vask/13/

Comment: Not certain about exact menaing of "ignore certain styles" ? Piece at post should remove _all_ `border-box` text from `style` elements. This does not affect `link` elements ; though, could , as @DavidThomas pointed out , parse `styleSheets` object - slightly more involved - to add/remove properties , as well. Is requirement to remove _all_ `border-box` within `style` ? , or only certain selectors ? If inspect `.customBox` at http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ca59vask/14/, should view `-webkit-box-sizing: ;` and `box-sizing: ;` having strike-through and no values . Thanks